# SharePoint show message with global css rules from Board body in layout page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, css

I have custom aspx page in layouts folder where i would like to show email bodies from discussion board. Currently im using Body attribute from Message content type. But now i get email message where is global CSS rule `table{max-width:450px;}` and this rule will break all my tables on page.
I look on standard discussion board in SharePoint and inspect the code. The rule mentioned in previous block was transformed to `D88BBB70091A4B439EA1997E93AD2E91 table {max-width:450px;}`. Is there any C# SharePoint code helper which can do this css "sandboxing" for me?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the was problem on different place. DiscussionMessage's Body attribute is parsed on update. In this parsing process there was some processing of css to prevent influencing other SharePoint form parts. My problem was thati I copy email message also to other list item and this list item has no same processing as discussion Message. The fix of this is to save Discussion message reload it to has processed content and after that copy body to some other place.